# querySelectAll and appending elements to html

Tags: javascript, html, css

The web browser seem to not show the results of a querySeletorAll from a css id, that was meant to create an list of words selected to from html to create a keywords list as an aside element. Is possible to look over the sequence of the for loop and why the list wasn't showing up on the html slot, it seems as if the elements were not appending to the page, when referenced.

The javascript is linked to the html page:

```
window.addEventListener("load",findKeyWords);
window.addEventListener("load", makeKeyStyles);

function findKeyWords(){
  var article = document.getElementById("doc");
  var aside =document.createElement("aside");
  aside.setAttribute("id", "keywords");
  var header = document.createElement("h1");
  var headertext = document.createTextNode("KeyWord List");
  var ol = document.createElement("ol");
  headerone= aside.getElementByTagName("h1")
  headerone.appendChild(headertext);
  document.getElementById("keywords").appendChild(header);
  document.getElementById("keywords").appendChild(ol);


  var keyWordElems = document.querySelectorAll("article#doc dfn");
  var keyWords = new Array(keyWordElems.length);

  for(int k = 0; k<keyWordElems.length; k++){
    keyWords[k]= keyWordElems;
    keyWords.sort();
    var linkId =replaceWs(keyWords[k]);
  }

  for(int i =0;i keyWordElems.length; i++){
    var linkId = replaceWs(keyWord[i]);
    var keyWordListItem = document.createElement('li');
    var keyWordLink = document.createElement('a');
    keyWordLink.setAttribute('href', "#keyword_" +linkID);
    keyWordLink.innerHTML = keyWords[i];
    keyWordListItem.appendChild(keyWordLink);
    ol.appendChild(keyWordListItem);
    $("doc").preappend("keywords"); 
  }
}


function makeKeyStyles(){
  var asidestyles = document.createElement("styles");
  document.aside.appendChild("asidestyles");
  document.styleSheets[document.syleSheets.length-1].insertRule(
    "aside#keywords{\
    border:3px solid rgb(101,101,101);\
    float: right;\
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;\
    padding: 10px;\
    width: 320px;\
    }\

    aside#keywords h1{\
    font-size: 2em;\
    margin: 5px;\
    text-align: center;\
    }\

    aside#keywords ol{\
    margin-left: 20px;\
    font-size: 1.2em;\
    }\

    aside#keywords ol li{\
    line-height: 1.5em;\
    }\

    aside#keywords ol li a{\
    color:rgb(101, 101,101); 
    text-decoration: none;\
    }",0);
}





/* Supplied Functions */

function replaceWS(textStr) {
  var revText = textStr.replace(/\s+/g,"_");
  return revText;
}
```

Comment: The code `document.querySelectorAll("article#doc dfn");` says: Find all elements whose tag name is `dfn` that are inside elements whose tag name is `article` and whose ID is `doc`. You haven't shown your HTML. Do you really have elements that match that selector?

Comment: i know what that is and what it supposed to do, however it seems like nieghter elements were appending to the html file,nor was I able to create a list of the words based on the selector. All the sequencing were written correctly according to the each command definition but it wasn't showing up on the browser.

Comment: The line `$("doc").preappend("keywords")` looks suspicious. Is that jQuery? If so, jQuery objects don't have a method called `preappend`. There's `.prepend()` and `.append()`.

Comment: I adjusted and still haven't couldn't have the aside come to view

Comment: Should each stylesheet rule be entered separately or in separate commas?

Comment: I also have the linkId variable equivalent, there was variable variation